# aplicar um filtro dentro de um loop for

Tags: python, loop

Tenho o seguinte dicionário:

```
dict_nome_anexo = {'JOAO': ['arquivo_joao.pdf'],
                       'CARLOS': ['arquivo_carlos.docx','arquivo_carlos.pdf'],
                       'MARIA': ['arquivo_maria.docx','arquivo_maria.png'],
                       'PEDRO': ['arquivo_pedro.pdf','arquivo_pedro.docx']}



dict_nome_anexo 

{'JOAO': ['arquivo_joao.pdf'],
 'CARLOS': ['arquivo_carlos.docx', 'arquivo_carlos.pdf'],
 'MARIA': ['arquivo_maria.docx', 'arquivo_maria.png'],
 'PEDRO': ['arquivo_pedro.pdf', 'arquivo_pedro.docx']}
```

O quê eu preciso é fazer um filtro de modo que restem apenas os arquivos "pdf" e, quando isso não for possível (no caso de "MARIA") preciso que permaneça o arquivo "docx". Minha dificuldade consiste extamente nesta última condição.

Fiz o seguinte:

```
lista_anexos = []                               # criei uma lista vazia

for nome,anexo in dict_nome_anexo.items():      # para nome,anexo no dicionário:
    
    if len(anexo) == 1:                         # se o comprimento dos elementos de anexo for igual a 1:
        lista_anexos.append(anexo)              # fazer o append do anexo na lista "lista_anexos"
    
    if len(anexo)>1:                            # se o comprimento dos elementos de anexo for maior que 1:
        for elemento in anexo:                  # para cada elemento do anexo:
            if elemento.endswith('pdf'):        # se elemento terminar com "pdf"
                lista_anexos.append([elemento]) # fazer o append deste elemento à lista "lista_anexos"
```

No entanto, não estou sabendo como proceder quando se trata de escolher entre 'arquivo_maria.docx' e 'arquivo_maria.png'.

Em suma, o resultado final pretendido é:

```
{'JOAO': ['arquivo_joao.pdf'],
 'CARLOS': ['arquivo_carlos.pdf'],
 'MARIA': ['arquivo_maria.docx'],
 'PEDRO': ['arquivo_pedro.pdf']}
```

Comment: Antes de dar uma resposta, tem alguns problemas que identifiquei ficarem em aberto em uma possível solução: 1) Na lista de anexos, podem haver mais um arquivo `.pdf`? Se houverem mais de um `.pdf` o que o algoritmo deve fazer? 2) Se não houverem nem `.pdf` e nem `.docx` na lista de anexos o que o algoritmo deve fazer?

Answer (score -1):

Seria possível continuar da forma que você fez. Isto é, analisando anexo por anexo e mantendo algumas flags caso já tenha visto um arquivo pdf ou docx.

Porém, para simplificar a leitura, você pode usar de [compreensão de lista](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compreens%C3%A3o_de_lista) para gerar uma segunda lista apenas com os elementos com a extensão desejada. Da seguinte forma:

```py
listaOriginal = ['a','a','b','b']
segundaLista = [elemento for elemento in listaOriginal if elemento == 'a']
```

Aplicando ao seu caso, temos:

```py
lista_anexos = []
for nome, anexos in dic.items():
    anexosPDF = [anexo for anexo in anexos if anexo.endswith('pdf')]
    anexosDOCX = [anexo for anexo in anexos if anexo.endswith('docx')]
    if anexosPDF: # Verifica se algum pdf foi encontrado.
        lista_anexos.extend(anexosPDF) # Adiciona todos os .pdf encontrados.
    elif anexosDOCX: # Verifica se algum docx foi encontrado.
        lista_anexos.append(anexosDOCX[0]) # Adiciona apenas um docx.
    else:
        pass # O que fazer quando não tem nenhum dos dois?
```

Para uma leitura mais aprofundada, sugiro pesquisar [aqui mesmo pelo site mesmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=compreens%C3%A3o+de+listas) sobre o tema de compreensão de listas.

Comment: Você não deixou claro em sua pergunta como deveria ser o comportamento em alguns casos específicos, mas como deu para entender sua dúvida, deixei a resposta. Para próximas perguntas, sugiro deixar mais claro essa parte. Um abraço e boa sorte!